# Chrome Dev tools track changes (html, css, js)

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools

I know that you can save js and css from chrome, and that sass is in for an experimental feature.

What I'm trying to achieve is a way to track all my changes in the browser when I live edit with my graphic designer. It doesn't seem like I can save html changes; especially considering most of it is generated.

Is there a chrome extension or future plans to do track changes/save them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Copy as HTML" in the DevTools Elements panel to save edited parts or even the text of the whole document. As you said most of the document is generated in runtime so it doesn't make much sense to save generated text per se.